# why phantomjs code doesn't go through array?

Tags: javascript, url, phantomjs, ubuntu-14.04

After running this code he save an infinite number of files with the source code of the first page("http://site1.com"), why he doesn't go through other links and doesn't stop ?

```
var args = ["http://site1.com", "http://site2.com", "http://site3.com"];

var fs = require('fs');
var i = 0;

function handle_page(file){
    page.open(file,function(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
            fs.write(i + '.html', page.content, 'w');
        });
        setTimeout(next_page,100);
   });
}

function next_page(){
   var file = args.shift();
   if(!file){ phantom.exit(0); }
   i++
   handle_page(file);
}
next_page();
```

Comment: The code that you show here **cannot** produce any files, because `fs.write()` is inside `page.evaluate()` which won't work. Please show your actual code.

Comment: actually the reason this code cannot produce any files is that the array is being **shift**ed so the next item is always at `[0]`

Comment: Artjom B: this code produce the same result with or without page.evaluate()  Tim: when it shift the first item, that item is deleted and returned, at the next iteration will be returned secodn item from array

Comment: @Tim Yes, this is probably the intended behavior. What's the problem with this?

Comment: ah yes, sorry. I was assuming the args were being accessed with `[i]` but clearly I didn't look properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context in PhantomJS. It doesn't have access to any variable defined outside. So you cannot reference `fs` or `page` inside of it and you don't need to, because `page.content` is available in the outer context:

```
page.open(file,function(){
    fs.write(i + '.html', page.content, 'w');
    setTimeout(next_page,100);
});
```

The remaining code looks fine.

Comment: I mentioned above that i tried that. it also produce an infinite number of files with 1..(infinite).html names each of them containing the source code of the first url

Comment: I see. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: i tried your code https://gist.github.com/artjomb/0a96a1f41dba377a1a4d and for me it works too, i don't understant what is with mine

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use and are you seening any errors for the above event handlers?

Comment: version 1.9.8, i started the code from your links (if that is what you meant to say) and it doesn't show nothing

Comment: interesting thing, after changin links in your code, it works fine but save files with source code of your links which i deleted

Comment: You mean it's solved? If not you can exchange my example urls with yours. I update the code in my link with the event handlers.

Comment: you solution is right, but there happens an error with my links, i wrote a comment for your code at github, please take a look

Comment: @VadimPlăcintă I just tried it with the first three of your URLs. You're right, there are some errors, but the `page.content` is correctly written. It seems that some external JavaScript code cannot be loaded. I tried with PhantomJS 1.9.8 and 2.0.1 and the three html source files are written correctly, but then again I'm on windows. This shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't think so, because the output was the same between 1.9.8 and 2.0.1.

Comment: if you observed, when he got that error he try again to load the same page, only first page is loaded right, the others are copies of the page which returned error, maybe there is an option to skip this page and go further

Comment: one more hilarious thing, if the second url which returned error is placed first in the array it is loading without error and that url which was loaded without error return an error if placed second in the array. maybe phantom need something like a reload after each loaded page, what do you think ?

Comment: Since I can't reproduce this, I can only suggest some things, like 1. change the user agent to Chrome 13: `page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1';` or try some commandline options like `--web-security=false --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`.

Comment: the same result, anyway thank you for the answers and the time you spent on this problem, now i found another way to get content that i need, not with phantomjs