# Creating page objects in a loop in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to retrieve the HTML of many distinct URLS. To do this, I'm iterating over an array of URLs and trying to create PhantomJS page objects (documentation [here](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html)).

For some reason, the **console.log** inside the **page.open** block isn't firing. Does anyone have any idea why? I can't find a similar problem on Google or Stack Overflow or PhantomJS documentation.

Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    urlToRequest = urlList[i];
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(urlToRequest, function (status) {
        console.log("Status code: ", status);
        phantom.exit()
    });
}
```

Comment: You probably have a problem with concurrency. You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code and probably exiting too early. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317439/why-phantomjs-code-doesnt-go-through-array) is a better way of doing this.

Comment: This should print at least one status line. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

By default console.log output from the page is suppressed. To print it out define an onConsoleMessage handler for the page object like is done below and it will print.

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
     console.log(msg);
};
```